# How to sort data selected from one table according to data in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have tables: post & votes
i want to sort the posts in table 'post' by count of column in table 'votes'.

```
SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY <SELECT count(*) as c FROM votes WHERE post = $row[srno]>
```

The 'votes' table contains 2 columns: post and user; It is meant to store votes of each post that exists in 'post' table.

```
SELECT count(*) as c FROM votes WHERE post = $row[srno]
```

Above query gives me the no. of votes of the specified post. How do i sort posts by this count?

Comment: What do you mean with `$row[srno]`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem its the id of the post...srno is a column in table 'post'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can all have from one table, votes:

```
SELECT COUNT(post) as c, post
FROM votes
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY post ASC;
```

Comment: "*How do i sort **posts** by this count?*" here you do not sort *posts*, but *votes*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `JOIN` for that:

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(*) as vcount
FROM post p
JOIN votes v ON v.post = p.srno
GROUP BY p.*
ORDER BY vcount
```

This will also add a column `vcount` to the table that contains the *number of votes*.

Note that this query will sort in **ascending** order so *lowest number of votes first*. You can use `DESC` to sort in *descending* order (so *highest number of votes first*):

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(*) as vcount
FROM post p
JOIN votes v ON v.post = p.srno
GROUP BY p.*
ORDER BY vcount DESC
```